# R.H. equivalent statement condition

Tags: reference-request, prime-numbers, gm.general-mathematics, riemann-hypothesis, prime-number-theorem

Is the  inequality $\prod \limits_{p \leq \sqrt{x}} (1+\frac{1}{p^2-1}) \prod \limits_{p \leq x} (1+\frac{1}{p}) \leq e^\gamma \ln(\theta(\sqrt{x})+\theta(x))$ where $\theta(x)$ is the Chebyshev's first function
true for all integers except finitely many equivalent to R.H. ?

also could anyone give a ref where is this equivalent is mentioned?

Comment: What is $\theta$ (I think it's one of Chebyshev functions, but better make sure)? Also, so you have any real reason to believe this to be true?

Comment: yes, its Chebyshev's first function. and secondly i don't know, i red it somewhere and i want to be sure its valid

Comment: If that's the case, you should definitely mention that in the question body and add the reference-request tag.

Comment: I think he meant by  $ \theta(x)$, The function which related to prime number defined as :  $\theta(x) = \sum_{p<=x}\log p$

Comment: The rate of growth of primes suggests the Chebyshev function might be useful here :https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem